# How is 'blaming customer service workers the same flawed and divisive logic'?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> [Penultimate para:] But the poor people working at the sharp end of customer service – the workers manning the phones the world over – aren’t the ones that deserve our ire. They aren’t the ones in control and they’re certainly not the ones benefiting financially. Ukip would have you believe that it is the working class immigrant population in this country that is responsible for an array of problems from unemployment to the housing crisis to the loss of cultural identity. **Blaming customer service workers is based on the same flawed and divisive logic.** [(Source)](http://www.theguardian.com/commentisfree/2014/oct/02/customer-service-kafkaesque-companies-bureaucracy-social-media?commentpage=1)

Would someone please explain what is meant by **logic** here? The penultimate sentence just expresses UKIP's belief "that it is the ... loss of cultural identity." In the last sentence, I infer that the author rejects this belief. Yet what's **flawed and divisive logic**? Isn't the author just rebuffing a belief?

Comment: The penultimate sentence is "Ukip would have you believe X": that is, "Ukip argues that X is so". The specific arguments they make are not given, but presumably you're supposed to know what these unstated arguments are (because they've been outlined earlier in the text, or because Ukip promulgates them in the community and they are consequently well-known). In any case, it is these unstated (in this text) arguments which the author refers to as the "flawed and divisive logic", and he asserts the same arguments, or analogous thought processes, are advanced in support of blaming customer service

Answer (score 3):

Beware that the following is from the point of view of the writer, and does not necessarily represent e.g., my point of view.

"Divisive" logic is a thought process that blames immigrants and "foreigners" living in the "here" for "our" problems. The writer is saying that if you agree that blaming "foreign" immigrants is wrong, you also shouldn't blame foreigners living abroad, interacting with our people over call centers.

"Flawed" logic (by the writer's definition) is blaming poor people such as immigrants and foreign call center workers (and by implication, native-born poor people) for "things," when "They aren’t the ones in control and they’re certainly not the ones benefiting financially."

In these instances, the writer is attacking the statements of "Ukip," who apparently blames call center workers and immigrants rather than their (richer) employers.

Comment: +1 Ukip is the UK Independent Party, whose agenda in many respects recalls the US Know-Nothings of the 1850s.

Comment: @StoneyB: Good to know. Was glad that I managed to identify the "bad guys" from the context without really knowing who they were. Had to change the references to "American," though.